# Necessity of MacTeX installation to work with LyX

Tags: lyx, mac

I want to install LyX on my Mac OS X.

It is said [here](http://www.lyx.org/Download#toc4) that "Before you install LyX you need to install a TeX system such as MacTeX."
What if I download LyX for Mac without installing a TeX system?

I am new to Mac and TeX in particular. Any explanation would by appreciated.

Comment: if you install lyx without a tex distribution, you will have a colourful program, but you will not be able to generate any output, such as pdf files.

Comment: So the whole role of the TeX system is to export the `.lyx` file into other formats?

Comment: The tex distribution does the hard work. It does the actual typesetting (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma/94910). Lyx is just a user-(un)friendly interface that helps in the handling of tex. To summarise: lyx is not necessary, it is just a "addon" to make things easier.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197765/what-is-the-difference-between-lyx-and-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install the MacTex distribution (http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html) like any other program on the Mac. It takes the "Unix pain" out of installing dozens of different programs and utilities.

Once you've run the MacTex installer you have a whole LaTex installation on the unix side of the Mac (which you won't see) and a few front-end applications such as TexShop and LaTexIt. Then, and only then, will you be able to use Lyx, which is another front-end and which relies on the whole LaTex installation in the background.

Do this and then the funny error message about which you asked in the other question will disappear (and people stop getting stroppy with you).