# Why does my citation turn?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing, lyx, cite-package

The top rows are all added citations and all were added in the reference file of lyx the same way but why does some of it becomes ? not a proper citation.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us some compilable TeX code?

Comment: @article{shankar_2015_finger,
  author = {Shankar, A and Sastry, P and Ram, A and Vamsidhar, A},
  pages = {10810-10814},
  title = {Finger Print Based Door Locking System},
  url = {http://www.kresttechnology.com/krest-academic-projects/krest-major-projects/ECE/BTech%20%20Major%20ECE%20EMBEDDED%202016-17/Btech%20ECE%20Embedded%20Major%20BP%202016-17/28.Finger%20Print%20Recognition%20Based%20Most%20Secured.pdf},
  volume = {4},
  year = {2015},
  journal = {International Journal of Engineering and Computer Science},
organization = {Dadi Institute of Engineering and Technology}
}

Comment: is that the tex code you mention?

Comment: No, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (follow the link to learn about what this means in this case).

Comment: @JasperHabicht They're using LyX. They're probably not writing (La)TeX "code" directly, so a (postable) MWE may be a tall order for them. They could try exporting the LaTeX code, but I'm not sure that'll identify the problem. This is one of the reasons I never recommend LyX: people think it's "easier" than learning the markup language, but it's actually much more difficult to figure out what's wrong when you do have a problem.

Comment: Here's a LyX-specific link for MWE: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. @frabjous I agree. In particular, I think that people should learn LaTeX well before considering LyX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197765/what-is-the-difference-between-lyx-and-latex).